# Magmi seems to update correctly but products grid doesn't reflect changes

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, products, magmi

[Magmi says](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/Update_existing_products) for updating products two columns are necessary:

- `sku`
- `store`

As it's not obvious what `store` should contain I use store code which is `english`. I went for updating two products as following:

```
"sku","store","name"
"100000000001","english","Test1"
"100000000008","english","Test2"
```

Selected the file containing above rows in `var/import` then chose `Update existing items only...`. It then took a few seconds to finish.

```
Runtime infos
Initialized attribute_set_infos!
Skus imported OK:2/2
```

Now as I see in both products edit pages, name fields are updated. But products grid in admin (`admin/catalog_product/index/`) doesn't reflect changes. It still shows previous values. This is where I ended:

```
mysql> select * from catalog_product_entity_varchar where entity_id = 5000 and attribute_id = 71;
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
| value_id | entity_type_id | attribute_id | store_id | entity_id | value |
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
|   601412 |              4 |           71 |        0 |      5000 | MS506 |
|   602135 |              4 |           71 |        1 |      5000 | Test1 |
+----------+----------------+--------------+----------+-----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.33 sec)
```

I tried to add `store_id` column in CSV header line with corresponding `0` values but it didn't change the one with `store_id=0` in above result set.

What am I missing in updating products with Magmi?

Comment: try with re-indexing from backend.

Comment: How do you think it is related to indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two store views and I had to update both: `admin` store which default values are stored in and `english` which is my current store code. Fortunately, Magmi accepts store codes separated by comma the same as below:

```
"sku","store","name"
"100000000001","english,admin","Test1"
"100000000008","english,admin","Test2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to launch reindex via `System > Index Management > Select All > Reindex Data > Submit`?

It seems to be index issue, as the values in the grid you're viewing are retrieved from the index tables in the DB, not from the ..._varchar, etc, tables.

Comment: Yes I'd done this `php shell/indexer.php --reindexall` before asking the question.

Comment: Have you flushed the cache after that?

Comment: No since all caches are disabled.

Comment: Did you notice the first row in output? That's the problem.